# Can't get DropDownList value shown in FormView ItemTemplate to appear in EditItemTemplate by default

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, webforms

I have an edit button and a dropdownlist inside a formview. I am using Linq To Entities to get the data I need to work with and have no problem populating and viewing the formview itemtemplate.

However, the dropdownlist control (`id="ddlEligibility"`) is only in the`edititemtemplate` (I use a textbox in the `itemtemplate` to display the current value) and I am having a problem getting the value initially shown in the itemtemplate to appear when the edititemtemplate is shown.  All I get right now is the dropdownlist with the first value shown.  I want the value from the itemtemplate to appear by default and the user can change it if they wish.  Here is the code that populates the dropdownlist.  Anyone have a suggestions?

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fvSubscriber.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
    fvSubscriber.DataBind(); 

    LifeLineDSEntities context = new LifeLineDSEntities():

    var program = from p in context.EligibilityPrograms
                  select p;

    DropDownList ddlEligibility = (DropDownList)(fvSubscriber.FindControl("ddlEligibility")));

    if (ddlEligibility != null)
    {
        ddlEligibility.DataSource = program;
        ddlEligibility.DataTextField = "ProgramName";
        ddlEligibility.DataValueField = "eligibilityCode";
        ddlEligibility.DataBind();
    }
}
```

DropDownlist in FormView...

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:FormView ID="fvSubscriber" runat="server" RenderOuterTable="false" DefaultMode="Readonly" OnModeChanging="fvSubscriberChanging">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtEligibility" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProgramName") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEligibility" runat="server" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
</form>
```

Comment: can you show me the line in ItemTemplate at where your textbox is binding?

Comment: @Bhavesh Kachhadiya I added the text box

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting the value of the textbox before you change the formview mode.

```
    TextBox txtEligibility= (TextBox)fvSubscriber.FindControl("txtEligibility");

    fvSubscriber.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
    fvSubscriber.DataBind(); 

    LifeLineDSEntities context = new LifeLineDSEntities():

    var program = from p in context.EligibilityPrograms
                  select p;

    DropDownList ddlEligibility = (DropDownList)(fvSubscriber.FindControl("ddlEligibility")));

    if (ddlEligibility != null)
    {
        ddlEligibility.DataSource = program;
        ddlEligibility.DataTextField = "ProgramName";
        ddlEligibility.DataValueField = "eligibilityCode";
        ddlEligibility.DataBind();
        if (txtEligibility != null)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEligibility.Text))
            {
                foreach (ListItem item in ddlEligibility.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Text == txtEligibility.Text)
                    {
                        ddlEligibility.SelectedValue = txtEligibility.Text;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  I ended up saving the textbox value to a global variable and then assigning that to my dropdownlist in Edit mode.  Now I have to do something similar to assign the value the user selects in edit mode when they click Save. Maybe it is just my inexperience with asp.net but it just seems this should be easier to do.

Comment: Yes it should be a fair bit easier as it usually only involves getting the value from ddlEligilibity.SelectedItem.Text/Value when the updating method gets called for your formview :)